# SQL: how to get only first users actions per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

```
actions
-------
user_id
action
date
```

How to select only first actions of each user?

Example data (action doesn't matter, let it be = 0):

- 1 0 2014-05-01
- 1 0 2014-05-02
- 1 0 2014-05-03
- 2 0 2014-05-01
- 2 0 2014-05-02
- 3 0 2014-05-08

Expected result:

- 1 0 2014-05-01
- 2 0 2014-05-01
- 3 0 2014-05-08

Comment: What concrete database? Different databases handling thing a bit differently - even if they all use SQL as their query language... please update your tags with `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using

Comment: postgresql for example

Comment: Not sure your allowed to name the field `date` without quotes. Edit: even if you can, not sure you should

Comment: I agree with vol7ron: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it's a reserved word, but mainly because it doesn't document the use of the column. Is that a "due date", a "done date", a "valid until date", ...?

Comment: it works without quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be solved using a window function (standard SQL)

```
select user_id, 
       action,
       date
from (
   select user_id,
          action,
          date,
          min(date) over (partition by user_id) as min_date
   from actions
) t
where date = min_date
order by user_id;
```

Using window functions is most probably faster than a self join on the table.

Using Postgres' `distinct on` operator is most probably faster than the solution using a window function (but that is not portable a other DBMS).

```
select distinct on (user_id) user_id, action, date
from actions
order by user_id, date
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae67f/6

Answer (score 0):

```
select a1.*
from actions a1
join
(
  select user_id, min(date) as mindate
  from actions
  group by user_id
) a2 on a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.date = a2.mindate
```

Comment: this query shows all actions by all users (I have added date to GROUP BY). Without it it shows error:ERROR:  column "actions.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Please add example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: My query should return for every user a single record from the smallest date for each user. Does it not?

Comment: Your query shows error:ERROR: column "actions.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function –

Comment: Please show your current query. I think you did not apply it correctly. Especially this part `min(date) as mindate`

Comment: yes, I've changed min to 'least', that's why it didn't work. Then I changed back to min. And it showed no error, but listed all actions of all users.

Comment: It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae67f/5 But you have a working solution anyway.